# How to check if textbox has attribute maxlength?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically i am adding `maxLength` to all textbox's dynamically but i want to add default `maxLength` to those text boxes that do not have a `maxLength` property set.

How can be this done using jquery, javascript?

Comment: Just check whether the property is `null`.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this:

```
if(!($("textbox").attr("maxLength"))){
    $(this).attr("maxLength", "100");
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks i was using maxlength instead of maxLength

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('input').attr('maxlength','6');
});
```

That would add maxlength attribute to all input fields